# JHIPSTER No access admin log and metrics

Tags: java, angular, jhipster

Since I upgrade my project from jhipster 5.82 to 6.1.0, I have no data in screnn admin Metrics and Logs

When I go on this screen, I have no data. In my console, I see error with HTTP Request :

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "<!doctype html> <html class="no-js" lang="fr" dir=…="app/global.bundle.js"></script></body> </html>
```

The requests called was :

```
http://localhost:8080/management/jhimetrics
http://localhost:8080/management/loggers
```

Is there error with implementation Angular 8 in Jhipster 6.1.0 ?